# How to selectively import and export specific content without overriding existing destination database?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I want my client to contribute content to the website, but the problem is, I'm simultaneously doing work on the site, modules, theming, adding stuff also etc...

I'm aware of the features module and can import and export selective tables with backup migrate or even phpmy admin, but it's tedious and error prone...

What data I want to import and export is:

```
- Content type
- Taxonomies
- Content itself including text and images(can ftp them manually no problem)
```

What would be an easy and simple solution for this without getting into code or shell access?

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, use [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module to transfer configuration.

For actual content, you will need to use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export stuff. Make a CSV file.

[VDE tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssOF3nPgcfc)

Then use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import the CSV file content into your other site.

[Feeds Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4)

Alternatively, for nodes you could just use [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export), but you will still need feeds for the taxonomy importing.

Comment: I looked online and it seems that feeds module cannot export CSV? Only import? "Feeds Import
sui_page commented 4 years ago
I've had luck with the Feeds module but the only downside is you can't export CSV's on page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2085307

Comment: Tried data import export module, not working either. https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import

Comment: Feed module doesn't register paragraphs fields, can't use VDE because I only need content items, not views, features is too complex for my client...isn't there an easy way to do this?

Comment: @BrunoVincent Use [Feeds Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_para_mapper). You can setup the view export so your client doesn't have to touch anything.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot, just tried https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export not working, the paragraph fields don't get exported, same as drupal.org/project/data_export_import , I'll try your recommendation and will post back if it works ;)

Comment: Ok, tried everything, nothing works, last attempt I did was as follows: Use views_data_export , created XML view, took the code and saved as XML and then used an importer I created with feeds module to import the XML file, it all works for very simple fields like "title" and "body" but doesn't work for paragraphs, even if they are mapped.